# How to delete overlapping faces without decimating entire geometry?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, clipping

I am trying to create a mask for a friend using 2 free models I downloaded.

https://free3d.com/3d-model/base-mesh-ready-to-be-rigged-15483.html

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sheep-skull-291dcb390c2f41e0a33e8df98883c291

However, part of the skull model overlaps inside of the head, and all of my attempts to fix this have failed. The Boolean modifier continuously deletes the mesh *outside* of the head or deletes one of the meshes entirely. Attemping to manually delete individual faces by hand is also deleting unnecessary faces from outside the head as well.

Blend file (blend-exchange would not work):https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ic6R66jSH9KRSNOYrKgQCg6pqY0pFUgr/view?usp=sharing

What I want the mask to look like:

[image]

The part that is clipping:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Nascarlaser1. It is usual for BSE users to see images in the body of the question. It makes it easier for people who are trying to answer questions when they do not need to follow links. Please post your images inside your questions in the future. I fixed it for you, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: It might also be helpful if you could share the .blend file. You can do that using https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry about the pictures! I will upload the .blend file asap

Answer (score 0):

you could use machine3tools addon
when enabled go to edit mode and press 3 for a clean up
it mostly works for me
there are other addons that can be useful for your scenario too
for example, you use the QuadRemesher addon to remesh  your asset so that the topology of your asset is better

Comment: I'll try these out, thanks!